# Issue hide export values radioButton in Acrobat Reader

Tags: eforms

How do I hide this message that Acrobat Reader shows?

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
%==========================================================
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eforms}

\everyRadioButton{
    \BC{0 0 0}% black
    \BG{1 1 1}% white
    \textColor{1 0 0}% red
    \symbolchoice{check}% default
}
\begin{document}
\medskip\hrule height 1pt\medskip
Question?
\par\bigskip \radioButton{button1}{10bp}{10bp}{true} Answer~1;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button1}{10bp}{10bp}{false} Answer~2;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button1}{10bp}{10bp}{false} Answer~3.
\medskip\hrule height 1pt\medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. If you don't want the user to know which one is true, use other values (e.g. A,B,C).

Comment: Thanks, @Ulrike Fischer. It fits.